# Can I dry digested protein sample over weekend in a vacuum concentrator?

Tags: proteins, digestion, mass-spectrometry

I have digested with trypsin the tissue protein extract for mass spectrometry, and forgot to transfer the sample from the SpeedVac to the -80C freezer. As I did this on Friday, I can transfer the samples only on Monday. Will this temper with my sample and subsequent protein identification?

Comment: I doubt there is any quality literature on this question, so the only way to find out is to try it. I suspect it would be fine but you should do some kind of risk analysis to determine whether you should just start again (ie the hassle of preparing a new sample versus the hassle of failed mass spec).

Answer (score 2):

If your sample dried in the speed-vac then it should not cause to much damage to the sample. But if Speed Vac stopped and there was some liquid left, then incubation at room temperature would result in hydrolysis and sample degradation ( also depends on the pH, neutral would be slower). Also you would have modifications to the amino acid side chains like oxidation and deamidation